# Webdriver IO - How to close the Basic Authentication Popup? Simulate pressing Escape?

Tags: node.js, webdriver-io, wdio

I am having trouble with the dreaded Basic Authentication popup.

I am testing a Store Front website.

When I go to the Home Page the Basic Authentication popup fires - I have got around this by sending the username and password in the url as follows:

```
https://username:password@url'
```

However somewhere along the journey the username/password is being lost and on the order confirmation page the Basic Authentication popup fires again and stops the page load from completing so I can't access the Order Confirmation ID - I can see the page in the background but the page load spinner is still spinning.

[image]

I can't resend the url at this point with the username and password.

If I MANUALLY press Escape the popup closes and then I can access the page.

I have been trying lots of different ways to simulate pressing Escape to close the popup but I can't get anything to work as shown below:

```
await browser.acceptAlert();
await browser.dismissAlert();
await browser.keys(Key.Escape);
await browser.action('key').down(Key.Escape).perform();
```

I also tried using Javascript but pressing Escape still had no effect.
I also tried to stop the page from loading using this but it didn't work

```
await browser.execute("window.stop();");
```

How can I get rid of the popup so I can access the page?